# Show a sub-menu using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help making a **sub-menu** appear **within 2s** after the page loads instead of when the user clicks on it. I'm using *JQuery*. That file is the *core* of the website. I need it to stay opened.

Here's the code I have at the moment, I tried to change that on.Click event but it didn't work.

The `handleSidenarAndContentHeight();` function resizes the menu items after the sub-menu appears.

```js
jQuery('.page-sidebar li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).next().hasClass('sub-menu') === false) {
        return;
    }
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    parent.children('li.open').children('a').children('.arrow').removeClass('open');
    parent.children('li.open').children('a').children('.arrow').removeClass('active');
    parent.children('li.open').children('.sub-menu').slideUp(350);
    parent.children('li').removeClass('open');
    parent.children('li').removeClass('active');

    var sub = jQuery(this).next();
    if (sub.is(":visible")) {
        jQuery('.arrow', jQuery(this)).removeClass("open");
        jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        sub.slideUp(350, function () {
            handleSidenarAndContentHeight();
        });
    } else {
        jQuery('.arrow', jQuery(this)).addClass("open");
        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("open");
        sub.slideDown(350, function () {
            handleSidenarAndContentHeight();
        });
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle or snippet

Comment: try to inspect and check the error if any!

Comment: By the way, are you familiar with the method `find` of jQuery? Instead of writing `parent.children('li.open').children('a').children('.arrow')` you can use `find` like this: `parent.find('li.open a .arrow')` or you can skip on the `a` tag: `parent.find('li.open .arrow')`. Just for you know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with a 2 second timeout should do the trick!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // Open Parent here

  setTimeout(function(){
    // Open Child here
  }, 2000)
});
```

Comment: That's great, but should I add the whole code inside of the document.ready { ? 

I'm kinda new to Javascript, sorry for those lazy questions

Comment: @LucazNunes It depends on you. You should wrap your functions calls inside the $(document).ready(). If not, your code could run before the elements are placed in the DOM. It's just to make sure that everything is ready and in place.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple javascript function you can use, the `setTimeout` function.

The code follows like this :

```
setTimeout(function() {yourFunctyion();}. delayTimeInMiliseconds);
```

This will call your function after the number of second(in ms).

There is also a plugin I've used. It has oneTime and everyTime methods.

[jQuery timers plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timer/)